# How to copy part of the string? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a string "2548 Tom White". I need to copy "2548" to one string and "Tom White" to another string. What would be the best solution to that?
I thought I will find the location of first space and the end of the string. Then first copy will be from the start to the first space and second copy will be from the first space to the end of the string. But I need to find location of the first space and the end of the string and then copy.

Comment: cf. string reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far or what idea you have so one can help to do it yourself.

Comment: Are you using the .NET framework? Then you could look at the `String::Split` method. This splits a string into a string array. Parameter is the delimiter. I'm not using the .NET framework so this is just a hint from me.

Comment: Ok, than you could take a look at the reference @Pierre posted. There you could take the `string::find_first_of` method to search for the first appearance of the delimiter (here SPACE?). Then you have the position the string which splits it into the two parts you need.

Comment: @Vegeta If you found my answer useful. please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use functions `find_first_of` and `substr`. Here is how you do it:

```
std::string s1 = "2548 Tom White";
size_t pos = s1.find_first_of(' ');
std::string s2 = s1.substr(0, pos);
std::string s3 = s1.substr(pos + 1);
```